# whats happen to this mysql query can anyone explain?

Tags: mysql

```
create table motors( 
 Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
 Name varchar(255),
 Type varchar(100),
 Gage float(3,2),
 Turn int(2),
 Rpm int(4),
 Sloat int(2),
Group varchar(255),
Wire_Weight float(3,2),
Connection varchar(100),
Remark text,Created_Date datetime,
Modify_Date datetime);
```

i got error 1064
Server version: 5.7.29

Comment: Maybe it's caused by the use of `Group` as a field name, which is also a reserved word?

Comment: `1064` is a syntax error. But MySQL actually returns more information than just the number. How are you inspecting errors? What tool are you using to run your SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

`Group` is a reserved term in MySQL. If you want you use names that are reserved you can use backticks, see the code below.

```
**Schema (MySQL v5.7)**


    create table motors
    (Id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT primary key,
    Name varchar(255),
     Type varchar(100),
     Gage float(3,2),
     Turn int(2),
     Rpm int(4),
     Sloat int(2),
     `Group` varchar(255),
     Wire_Weight float(3,2),
     Connection varchar(100),
     Remark text,
     Created_Date datetime,
     Modify_Date datetime
    );

---
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mzP8hwr3XXwE2CBLgsc7G1/2)

Comment: @DavidMakogon Sorry, fixed. I am having that day of the month...

Comment: @user3783243 Sorry, reed my first comment to this :) , you are right, and I edited the post.

Comment: @kishorthite Please read edited post. You don't have to rename it. Glad it helped.